# AngularJS docs - how are they generated?

Tags: angularjs, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

The [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#directive) is clear and easy to read - how is it generated?

If using JSDoc, is the style sheet available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use dgeni to generate the docs: https://github.com/angular/dgeni

Comment: Thanks. The question was good enough to answer but not to vote for: what's with that? How is SO supposed work?

Comment: I don't know, can you accept it at least?

Comment: Sure I can. But why didn't you vote up the question if you thought if worth answering?  I'm still trying to work out how SO works.

Comment: @LeeGee If you copy paste your question into the google, you will get answer there easy. Try to solve the problem (?) and ask after. That's how SO works.